# Chrome Extension Content ->Background message passing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

Whats up with this?

content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({message: "whats the url"}, function(response) {
    alert(response.hereistheurl);
});
```

background

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message) {
        var taburl = sender.tab.url;
        alert("the background is trying to send " + taburl);
        sendResponse = ({hereistheurl: "taburl"});
    }
    else {
        alert("trying")
        var tabnumber = sender.tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.update(tabnumber, {url: request.gohere});
    }
  });
```

The else is working fine.  When the if statement is true,the background tries to send a response, but I see nothing in the content script.

Comment: Hint `sendResponse` is a function...

Comment: @RobW Yeah!  Thanks, removed the equal sign and it works now.